# DX12, How to implement a standard texture class?

Tags: textures, directx-12

I'm working on the texture class of our engine and I came across one problem.

Our API supports different actions like updating some texels of the texture and reading data from the texture.

This texture could be bound to the pipeline as an UAV or maybe as a SRV. It could also be created as a RTV or a DSV.

How should I approach the creation and updates of textures? Should I just create all textures as *UPLOAD* heaps? This will be the most standard solution as I will easily read and write from/to the data, but it also means less GPU bandwidth.

I could also detect if I'm creating a texture from file or a procedural texture, in the first case I will upload the texture to a *DEFAULT* heap.

What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take al look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12), in particular the ``DescriptorHeap`` and ``ResourceUploadBatch `` classes

Comment: Hi @ChuckWalbourn , yeah your code will be really helpful to understand some things, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to create texture in the upload heap, you would face an eternal cycle of validation error while trying to solve them. It is because texture are not using a linear representation in memory. But at least for you, the copy and update operations are the simplest of your concerns here.

When you want to perform transfer between the CPU and the GPU, you need to create a buffer in the upload or readback heaps, use `GetCopyableFootprints` to know how to store/read the image in it and call `CopyTextureRegion` to perform the actual copy. This is a few pages of codes if you want to support partial updates and reads, but this operations are straightforward.

After that, many consideration can influence your texture class, how you want to abstract the views in descriptor heaps, do you want to support reserved textures with partial residency, do you want to support memory aliasing, how do you manage the lifetime of textures in use by the gpu while updating/destroying them, streaming, etc. There is no perfect and solve it all solutions and it all depends on your needs.

Comment: Hi @galop1n , lets say that I want to implement a _ReadTexel()_ method, my idea is to create a _READBACK_ resource, and copy the data from the _DEFAULT_ resource. However, the _ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::CopyTextureRegion()_ will be executed much after the ReadTexel() returned, how could I handle this? Maybe I should have a _CopyCommandList_ and I should send this command there so I would be able to execute it inside the _ReadTexel()_ method ?
 Thanks!

Comment: @Nacho `ReadTexel` is not a recommended operation unless really necessary and should never synchronize GPU and CPU! If it is on a resource created from CPU memory, then just tag your image to not discard the memory and pay the extra storage price. If it is a `ReadTexel` to a GPU generated surface, then you have to think it as a `std::future`. You trigger the copy then in an asynchronous way, wait for the operation to be complete before reading it back.You do that by inserting a `ID3D12Fence` after executing `CopyTextureRegion` and wait for it to reach the proper value.

Comment: yeah I figured out that it has to be a really expensive operation! Is funny  because in Dx11 you could do it without much complication so I guess that the driver internally would be doing a lot of things. I like your approach of future, but that will mean that I will be without the results for quite some time. What do you think about having a separate CopyCmdList?

Comment: The same recommendations apply to D3D11, you just wait a few frames or use queries to wait for completion in order to not sync CPU and GPU. And in regard to using the copy queue, you can and should, but it also mean using a fence before the copy to wait for the generated surface in the first place, it will not get you the result faster.